# How to make Vim not be a line editor

Tags: vimrc, wrapping, line-numbers, navigation

Vim is famously (or infamously) a child of line-based editing. For many cases this is acceptable. But I wish to use it primarily as an academic tool with large amounts of text. I want the experience to feel oriented around visual lines as opposed to logical lines. Let me flush out some of what that means:

- jk are both mapped to gj and gk respectively.
- gj and gk are mapped to j and k respectively.
- commands such a 4j and 4k work on visual lines.
- commands such as 4d work on visual lines.
- relative line numbering and absolute line numbering both work with visual lines and not logical lines.

The first is implemented with remapping:

```
nnoremap <expr> j v:count ? 'j' : 'gj'
nnoremap <expr> k v:count ? 'k' : 'gk'
```

I'm sure with extensive creativity and work many of the other asks and more can be achieved. Has anyone done this before? It seems like a lot of work and something that could be implemented as a plugin. If not does anyone have part of a vimrc file that implements this functionality that they are willing to share? Or perhaps there is a mode in vanilla vim that has this behavior and I am just overlooking it?